# Place green tick icon in angular control after validation

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place a green tick in the e-mail input control after the successful validation of its content. Something like the following

```
        <label for="useremail">User E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" formControlName="useremail" class="form-control"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f['password'].errors }" />
            <span *ngIf="submitted && myForm.valid">Tick</span>
            <span *ngIf="submitted && !myForm.valid">X</span>
        </div>
```

... but want to replace the word `Tick` with the green tick image(icon).
Is there a simple way of displaying a green tick icon upon successful validation in the right upper corner of the angular control. I thought there is a bootstrap class that I add to control that would a trick - I spent hours on internet without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simple way is to use any icon library and theme color class which can help easily to add gree tick icon. `<i class="bi bi-check"></i>`.
[Bootstap icons link] https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/check/
But i would rather prefer a toast library to show a message. And prefer to use primeng toast library
[Link] http://primefaces.org/primeng/toast

Answer (score 1):

I found the very simple solution - I am adding `is-valid` class to input element. This puts green tick at the right hand side of input element.